# Хочу перекачать часть постов со старого сайта на новый, но INSERT в новую базу дает ошибку SELECT в старой

Tags: wordpress

На моем хостинге есть два сайта, каждый из которых привязан к своей базе данных. Оба на Wordpress. Я пытаюсь сделать два отдельных подключения к двум базам данных и из одной скачать, а в другую положить информацию. Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

$servername2 = "localhost";
$database2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$username2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password2 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$conn2 = mysqli_connect($servername2, $username2, $password2, $database2);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts";

$counter = 600;

$iterator = 1;

if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    foreach($result as $row){

        $stringArr[] = "(" . $counter . ", '" . $row['post_author'] . "', '" . $row['post_date'] . "', '" . $row['post_date_gmt'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_content'] . "', '" . $row['post_title'] . "', '" . $row['post_excerpt'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_status'] . "', '" . $row['comment_status'] . "', '" . $row['ping_status'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_password'] . "', '" . $row['post_name'] . "', '" . $row['to_ping'] . "',
        '" . $row['pinged'] . "', '" . $row['post_modified'] . "', '" . $row['post_modified_gmt'] . "',
        '" . $row['post_content_filtered'] . "', '" . $row['post_content_filtered'] . "', " . $row['post_parent'] . ",
        '" . $row['guid'] . "', " . $row['menu_order'] . ", '" . $row['post_type'] . "', '" . $row['post_mime_type'] . "',
        " . $row['comment_count'] . ")"; 
/*        
        if($iterator%50 == 0) {
            print_r($stringArr);

            exit;
        }*/
        $iterator++;
        $counter++;
 /*       
        print_r($string);
        
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO serjam_wp1.wp_post VALUES (" . $string . ")";

        if ($conn2->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
        */
 //       print_r($string);
         
    }
}

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO serjam_wp1.wp_post VALUES (" . implode(",", $stringArr) . ")";

        if ($conn2->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
```

Если я просто вывожу в браузер содержимое бд, где информация и так лежит, то все прекрасно получаю.

То есть, если нет кода INSERT, то скрипт работает. А вот если он есть, то SELECT перестает работать. Скрипт запускаю с сайта, где находится информация.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда так не делай, если не хочешь поломать базу.
А для переноса постов (и не только) в ВП есть стандартный инструмент экпорта-импорта.

[image]

Comment: а как найти этот инструмент, я даже не понимаю, что конкретно в интернете запрашивать..

Comment: @Valentin обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!